What American movies are being referenced in the ending of Run for The Money: The Great Mission?
The ending for episodes 50-62 of the anime Run for the Money: The Great Mission, (the one featuring bilimi), shows characters from the show in costumes and poses referencing various American movies. I've been able to figure out all of the references except for two.

0:16 - West Side Story
0:24 - Don Quixote
0:28 - Blues Brothers
0:33 - Wizard of Oz
0:38 - ???
0:45 - ???
0:48 - Little Shop of Horrors
0:56 - Saturday Night Fever

0:38 in the credits shows Sid Phoenix in a white suit with a red flower and a cane. He is holding a white top hat above him.

0:44 shows Pieta Barone in a black suit, Sarah Peabody in a sparkling purple dancer outfit with a yellow top hat and jacket and leggings, and Claire Summers in a maid outfit. They are surrounding a black and white logo of a radio tower with the text "An RFM Picture".

What American movies are these two scenes referencing in the Run for the Money outro?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0VeEqonEa0?

@Valorum What part of the video is getting referenced?

An "RFM Picture" should be "RKO Picture". Presumably RFM is Run For Money

@Valorum Do you want to post that as an answer?

Honestly I feel like it's more of a comment
